# how do Arch system upgrades work compared to ubuntu/apt?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I'm in this position on Kubuntu 19.10 in which I can't update or install packages via apt because Kubuntu 19.10 is too old.  I can't even update Kubuntu itself.  I'm just stuck and apparently there's a way to un-stuck this by manually editing `sources.list` or some such... but my system never warned me that I ought to do system upgrade.... and I WANT THIS TO NEVER HAPPEN AGAIN.

I have a long history of `apt` giving me reasons for rage and I've thought of switching to Arch.  But I have no idea if this particular issue with system updates would happen just as easily with Arch.

Anyone able to speak to how Arch system upgrades work when a release becomes unsupported?

Comment: Do some research about [rolling release](https://itsfoss.com/rolling-release/) model first, and if you don't understand something, then ask a question.

Comment: With that difference pointed out, I guess the main question is: **what happens if my Arch system becomes out of date?**  Say I don't perform updates for a while... does anything explode?  Do I get left with a broken-can't-be-updated-without-greuling-effort scenario?

Comment: "does anything explode?" Many years ago, I had ArchLinux on a fileserver. Not understanding the concept of rolling releases, I left it un-updated for months. Eventually there was a need to update it (some software didn't work or could not be installed), but it was too late - my system was too old, and updates were refused. Conclusion: While you can leave your Centos 5 or even-numbered Ubuntu installation alone for years, ArchLinux (and perhaps odd-numbered Ubuntu) forces you to provide constant love and caring. It's designed for that.

Comment: Wow, good to know that updates can be refused and result in a stuck system!  @berndbausch you pointed out the *odd-numbered Ubuntu* which makes me wonder if my current "stuck" position would not have occurred if I was using LTS?

Comment: Well, LTS is valid for how many years? 8? 10? I guess herein lies part of your answer. Regarding my Archlinux experience, you can still read about it online: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1452148#p1452148.

Comment: Correction: Updates were not refused, but led to a totally unusable system. Which is worse, in my opinion. I think the conclusion is that you should not use Archlinux if you are not ready to look after it on a regular basis.